# Is it possible to retrieve the current bar's color?

Tags: pine-script

I'd like a quick way to determine if the current bar is bullish or bearish. I can only find the barColor() function which sets the bar color; I'd like to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has no visibility on the actual color of the bars, but it knows price information, so the candle's state can be derived using a boolean expression like:

```
upBar = close > open
```

Comment: I think the problem is when changing bar bgcolor, a developer would like to know the color of the default setting (whatever the user has set for his up/dn bar color via settings on the chart).  it helps when changing colors of bars, so to be able to set it back to default when appropriate.

Comment: We have logged your request. Thx for the suggestion.